# Natural language processing with a continuous dependent variable

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training, natural-language-processing, learning-algorithms

I have a large number of observations. Each observation contains:

- dependent variable: a scores ranging from 0 - 100
- independent variable: a large article

I want to know which words or phrases predict a higher score.

I know that for discrete dependent variables, Naive Bayes can be used for this task. How do I conduct this analysis with a continuous dependent variable?

Comment: As described on the below question, there would be no problem with Naive Bayes and continuous and discrete variables together. Or is the dependency something that brakes the rule?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136577/how-to-deal-with-mixture-of-continuous-and-discrete-features-when-using-naive-ba

Comment: Yes, that question has continuous variables as predictors. However, it has a discrete variable which it wishes to predict. I wish to predict a continuous variable.